# the change is not applied on index.php

Tags: php, html, css

I have this index.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <?php include('includes/header.php');?>
    <?php include('includes/sidebar.php');?>
    <?php include('includes/content.php');?>
    <?php include('includes/footer.php');?>
</body>
</html>
```

and these including files.

header.php

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="banner.jpg">
</div>
```

sidebar.php

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <a href="index.php" class="sidebar">Home</a><br />
    <a href="study.php" class="sidebar">Study</a><br />
    <a href="calendar.php" class="sidebar">Calendar</a><br />
    <a href="diary.php" class="sidebar">Diary</a>
</div>
```

footer.php

```
<div id="footer">
    <p>haha</p>
</div>
```

and I have this css file.

```
#container{
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    width:1024px;
    border:3px;
}
#header{
    margin-left:50px;
    border:3px;
}
#sidebar{
    margin-left:30px;
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    height:900px;
    border:3px;
}
#sidebar a:link{
    color : #ff6c00;
    text-decoration : none;
}
#sidebar a:visited{
    color :  #ff6c00;
    text-decoration : none;
}
#sidebar a:hover{
    color : #00991d;
    text-decoration : underline;
}
#content{
    margin-left:30px;
    float:left;
    width:724px;
    height:900px;
    border:3px;
}
#footer{
    border:3px;
    text-align:center;
    clear:both;
    width:1024px;
}
```

The setting about the link on the sidebar is working properly. However, I change some margin and border so that I can check whether it's working or not, and it's not working. I refreshed the site and nothing new show up.

Could you help me figure out why this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried a hard refresh (Ctrl+F5 on Windows, Command + R on Mac)?

Comment: Did you try clearing the browser cache?

Comment: make sure css file is on root and not in any "css/" folder.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should try out changes in css, with some sort of development tools, and not with refresh (for obvious cache problems, and because you try out the setting before you commit them).

Examples for such tools are the [chrome development tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index) for Chrome or [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) for Mozilla.

Meanwhile, you can try refreshing with ctrl+R or some other 'hard refresh' method (browser dependent).

Last, but not least, you should also check if you actually managed to upload the eltered files to the server, and no error occurred during the process. Sometimes the ftp connection to a server breaks and the program fails to upload the file.